# MySQL - Trigger error on row update

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I am trying to implement a trigger to auto increment a field on the row update. Each time an existing row in PERSON table is updated, i want consistency_version to be incremented by one automatically.

My table:

```
CREATE TABLE PERSON (
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
consistency_version INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
name    CHAR (100) NOT NULL,
);
```

and Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER consistency_version_trigger BEFORE UPDATE ON PERSON
FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.VERSION = @VERSION+1
```

When I execute an update statement on a row in the table i expect the consistency_version to increment by one

But i get the following error:

```
Column "consistency_version" cannot be null
```

Can anyone advise what im doing wrong? I think @VERSION is null. How can i set this value to the version of the current row that is being updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is that '@version' is returning NULL. This would cause @version + 1 to result in null, and then attempt to set the not-nullable consistency_version column to null, resulting in an error.

Have you tried using OLD instead?

`CREATE TRIGGER consistency_version_trigger BEFORE UPDATE ON PERSON` 
`FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.VERSION = OLD.VERSION+1`

Answer (score 1):

@VERSION is a session variable. It exists and is visible only during the session which created it. So you are basically saying `SET NEW.VERSION = NULL + 1` which is NULL.

*Assuming the builtin autoincrement feature doesn't fit your needs for some reason:*

To create an global auto incrementing value you need to use a table.
Create a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `consistency_version` (
    `consistency_version` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
INSERT INTO `consistency_version` VALUES(1);
```

And then get the next number like this:

```
UPDATE consistency_version SET consistency_version = LAST_INSERT_ID(consistency_version +1);
SET NEW.VERSION = LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

This uses LAST_INSERT_ID as a temporary place to hold the next number. You can get more info about this in [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id).

It is also important for the sequence table to be MyISAM to avoid locking it for a long time during transactions.

Comment: thanks for your response, but i need to maintain a version per row and not globally. I was checking the manual and i believe OLD.VERSION works instead of using a variable.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirements correctly , following will solve your problem

```
CREATE TRIGGER `TgrNAME` BEFORE UPDATE ON `PERSON` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    set new.consistency_version = new.consistency_version +1 ;
 END
```